# Have an "Circular reference in value argument not supported" error with JSON.stringify() when used with an object

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, stringify

My function creates an object and send it to another function:

```
function Function1(){

    var id = '@Html.Raw(Model.ID)';
    var amount = '@Html.Raw(Model.Amount)';
    var desc = '@Html.Raw(Model.Description)';

    var data = { ID: id, Amount: amount, Desc: desc };

    Function2(data)
}
```

And Function2, takes that data and tries to `stringify` it before sending it with `Ajax` request:

```
function Function2(data){

 var URL = this.element.attr("url") 
 var sendData;

  if(data != null){      
     sendData = JSON.stringify(data);
  } 

  $.ajax(
    {
        url: URL,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "html",
        data: sendData,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            var dialog = $("#mainWindow").data("kendoWindow");
            $("#dataWin").html(result);
            dialog.open();
        }
    })

}
```

When executing `JSON.stringify(data)` logic, I'm getting an error:

> Circular reference in value argument not supported

Why is that and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: is there any other code we should know about ?

Comment: what are the values of id, amount and desc? How do you call Function1?

Comment: The only code I have is an `Ajax` call in Function2 which is using `dataToSend` and parameters setting in Function1 like `var ID = '@Html.Raw(Model.ID)'`

Comment: I will update the description

Comment: Can you try renaming data to something like myData (function Function2(data)) and check once

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is any circular reference in your code as shown below.

```
var john = new Object();  
var mary = new Object();  
john.sister = mary;  
mary.brother = john;  
  
// This line causes a runtime error.  
var error = JSON.stringify(john);
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/misc/circular-reference-in-value-argument-not-supported